# Unmarshal XML Into a Map

Tags: xml, go

As the title states I am trying to unmarshal my XML directly into a map instead of having to first unmarshal into a struct and then convert the struct into a map. I am dealing a fairly large data set and the dual conversion is taking more time than desired.

If anyone could provide any guidance on this at all it would be greatly appreciated.

XML: The classAccesses repeat and there are a few other elements.

```
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>AccountRelationUtility</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
```

My current struct: I parse out each of the header elements first and then create a new struct with the child elemtnts

```
type classAccesses struct {
    ApexClass string `xml:"apexClass"`
    Enabled   string `xml:"enabled"`
}

type diffs struct {
    ClassAccesses []classAccesses `xml:"classAccesses"`
}
```

Desired map: I want to keep the diffs struct, but I want the child struct "ClassAccesses" to become similar to the below map.

```
map[string]string {
    "ApexClass": "enabled"
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I added the XML along with some additional details on exactly what I am after.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066758/how-can-i-write-an-array-of-maps-golang#23066950) answer, maybe it can help you to convert the unmarshalled arrays to maps (_after you did the unmarshalling from the xml_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Go 1.3, it is not possible to unmarshal an XML document directly into a map using the standard Go library.

The XML part of the standard library is given here, http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/, there are no functions to do exactly what you ask for in the question.

Depending on the specifics of your situation, you may have other options such as:

- Parallelise your algorithm, i.e. read from the file and decode at the same time. This will only work well if you have multiple files to read from.
- Write your own XML decoding algorithm in Go.

Comment: This is really unfortunate... Guess I will just have to Parallelise the algorithms for both of my files. The goal is to compare two files and list out the diffs.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a type that implements the [xml.Unmarshaller interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler) then you can marshal your data directly into a map[string]string.

```
type classAccessesMap struct {
    m map[string]string
}

func (c *classAccessesMap) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    c.m = map[string]string{}

    key := ""
    val := ""

    for {
        t, _ := d.Token()
        switch tt := t.(type) {

        // TODO: parse the inner structure

        case xml.StartElement:
            fmt.Println(">", tt)    

        case xml.EndElement:
            fmt.Println("<", tt)
            if tt.Name == start.Name {
                return nil
            }

            if tt.Name.Local == "enabled" {
                c.m[key] = val
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a partial solution; https://play.golang.org/p/7aOQ5mcH6zQ