# Golang xml unmarshal: Only root element gets unmarshaled if we use a Xml name element in the nested structs

Tags: xml, go

We have an Xml as given below

```
<Test>
        <Test1>
            <Data>999</Data>
        </Test1>
</Test>
```

The Go struct used for unmarshalling is as given below

```
type Root struct{
    XMLName xml.Name
    ChildElem Child
}
type Child struct{
   XMLName xml.Name 
   Data string `xml:"Data"`
}
```

While **Marshaling** a struct with assigned values we get the expected xml as mentioned above. However while **unmarshaling** the above xml into the Root struct, only the root element tag are parsed while the nested elements remain empty.
Is this an expected behavior ?

Link to playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uUPO0gBNCp8

Comment: *"Is this an expected behavior ?"* -- Yes, unmarshaling the root element is obvious, there's only one argument to be passed in to `xml.Unmarshal`. However unmarshaling nested elements that don't have a matching field isn't as obvious, say if you have more than just one `ChildElem` field, and those fields' names do not match the xml's elements, `xml.Unmarshal` would have to do some not-at-all clear choices to decide which element to unmarshal into which field... Just be specific, don't expect the unmarshaler to do *all* the work and provide the fields with names to match the xml.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/oImB7hutsn_-

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
type Root struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name
    ChildElem Child `xml:"Test1"`
}
```

If you do not specify a struct tag with the name of the XML element, then the xml package will use the variable name for it, in your case "ChildElem" which is not what you want here.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I am aware that this setting  works. However, my use case is to have dynamic names for the Root Tag and the tag of the child tag. In this case, only the root tag gets parsed, and the child tag does not

Comment: I see, that was not clear from your question. So you want to parse XML that has different names? Basically you want to parse a different XML tree?

Comment: Is this maybe what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723876/unmarshal-xml-into-a-map

Comment: For instance I need to be able to parse one xml like this  <Test>
        <Test1>
            <Data>999</Data>
        </Test1>
</Test>
and another one like <Root>
        <Test2>
            <Data>999</Data>
        </Test2>
</Root>       into the same struct mentioned in the question.

Comment: Alright, that question I cannot answer right now. I am not sure Go's xml package supports this use-case.

Comment: @RohitKar the only way to unmarshal different xml documents into a single struct is by implementing the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface, which in this specific example is not too difficult. However if you are working with more complex documents and all of them different at multiple levels of nesting, then implementing the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface is going to be more PITA than simply declaring a struct for each document.