# Unmarshal SOAP message with Go

Tags: go, soap

I'm relatively new to the go language.

I have a problem trying to unmarshal a SOAP message. My attempt is to abstract the content of the Body element and avoid defining the XML structure statically, as it changes depending on the requested action.
Unfortunately I can't find a way to do this correctly. In the example, the GetContent function should receive a pointer to the struct that contains the content and add it dynamically to the Body, in order to be filled. But the result is not the expected one.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Message interface{}

type EnvelopeResponse struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Envelope"`
    Body    Message  `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Body"`
}

type Body struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Body"`

    Fault               *Fault  `xml:",omitempty"`
    Content             Message `xml:",omitempty"`
    SOAPBodyContentType string  `xml:"-"`
}

type Fault struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Fault"`

    Code   string `xml:"faultcode,omitempty"`
    String string `xml:"faultstring,omitempty"`
    Actor  string `xml:"faultactor,omitempty"`
    Detail string `xml:"detail,omitempty"`
}

type GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse struct {
    XMLName                xml.Name `xml:"urn:dslforum-org:service:Hosts:1 GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse"`
    NewHostNumberOfEntries int64    `xml:"NewHostNumberOfEntries"`
}

func GetContent(rawXml []byte, content interface{}) {
    envelope := EnvelopeResponse{Body: Body{Content: content}}
    xml.Unmarshal(rawXml, &envelope)
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<u:GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse xmlns:u="urn:dslforum-org:service:Hosts:1">
<NewHostNumberOfEntries>47</NewHostNumberOfEntries>
</u:GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
`)
    content := &GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse{}
    GetContent(b, content)
    fmt.Println(*content)
}
```

Here the example in the playground:

https://go.dev/play/p/BBR4vEXiPbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to use generics to represent the variable and parameterized content of the body.

This code works as I expect:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type EnvelopeResponse[T any] struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Envelope"`
    Body    Body[T]  `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Body"`
}

type Body[T any] struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Body"`

    Fault               *Fault `xml:",omitempty"`
    Content             T      `xml:",omitempty"`
    SOAPBodyContentType string `xml:"-"`
}

type Fault struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Fault"`

    Code   string `xml:"faultcode,omitempty"`
    String string `xml:"faultstring,omitempty"`
    Actor  string `xml:"faultactor,omitempty"`
    Detail string `xml:"detail,omitempty"`
}

type GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse struct {
    XMLName                xml.Name `xml:"urn:dslforum-org:service:Hosts:1 GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse"`
    NewHostNumberOfEntries int64    `xml:"NewHostNumberOfEntries"`
}

func GetContent[T any](rawXml []byte, content T) {
    envelope := EnvelopeResponse[T]{Body: Body[T]{Content: content}}
    xml.Unmarshal(rawXml, &envelope)
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<u:GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse xmlns:u="urn:dslforum-org:service:Hosts:1">
<NewHostNumberOfEntries>47</NewHostNumberOfEntries>
</u:GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
`)
    content := &GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse{}
    GetContent(b, content)
    fmt.Println(*content)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use some interface{}, Why? Follow is test pass code:
https://go.dev/play/p/OPkNScHjri1

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Message interface{}

type EnvelopeResponse struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Envelope"`
    Body    Body
}

type Body struct {
    XMLName                        xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Body"`
    GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse
    Fault                          *Fault  `xml:",omitempty"`
    Content                        Message `xml:",omitempty"`
    SOAPBodyContentType            string  `xml:"-"`
}

type Fault struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Fault"`
    Code    string   `xml:"faultcode,omitempty"`
    String  string   `xml:"faultstring,omitempty"`
    Actor   string   `xml:"faultactor,omitempty"`
    Detail  string   `xml:"detail,omitempty"`
}

type GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse struct {
    XMLName                xml.Name `xml:"urn:dslforum-org:service:Hosts:1 GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse"`
    NewHostNumberOfEntries int64    `xml:"NewHostNumberOfEntries"`
}

func GetContent(rawXml []byte) *EnvelopeResponse {
    envelope := EnvelopeResponse{}
    xml.Unmarshal(rawXml, &envelope)
    return &envelope
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse xmlns:u="urn:dslforum-org:service:Hosts:1">
            <NewHostNumberOfEntries>47</NewHostNumberOfEntries>
        </u:GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
`)
    envelope := GetContent(b)
    fmt.Println(envelope)
}
```

```
&{{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Envelope} {{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envel
ope/ Body} {{urn:dslforum-org:service:Hosts:1 GetHostNumberOfEntriesResponse} 47} <nil> <nil> 
}}
```

Comment: Yes, putting the exact type inside the Body it works. But that's not what I wanted. So I'm forced to define a Body type for each response, as well as the response type itself.

Comment: it is another problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723876/unmarshal-xml-into-a-map